# In SVG.js why does the clear() method throw an error in this example?

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

In this example below, why does the `draw.clear()` method throw the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined at create.clear`? What can I do to get the clear method to work and not throw any errors?

```
import * as SVG from 'svg.js';
import 'svg.filter.js';

// create the svg
let draw = new SVG.Doc('root');
draw.size('100vw', '100vh');

// create a rect with a dropshadow
let rect = draw.rect(100, 50).x(50).y(80).fill('red').stroke({
  color: 'green',
  width: 10
})

draw.clear()
```

[image: Edit webpack and svg.filter.js example]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I updated the question with the error. You can also just click on that big blue button to see the error.

Comment: I know I could have clicked on the big blue button, but why should I have to leave Stack Overflow to see a simple error message? If you want help, put some effort into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I forked your code and tried using `draw.remove()` instead of `draw.clear()`, and that appears to work. This appears to be a glitch in the version of SVG.js you are using - as I've only used the regular JS version, I'm not sure where your problem is - but you should try the Github issues site for SVG.js and post there, FuzzyMa is active and helps a lot of folks out. I did find an issue on the Github site that could be related, regarding the [Typescript compiler](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/752).

Comment: I did as you suggested and posted an issue and FuzzyMa provided an answer rather quickly. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome - he is super helpful. I'm happy you are using svg.js, it's a great library.

Comment: any way I could get an upvote? Would love to get to 125 so my votes would count!

Answer (score 1):

FuzzyMa provided [the answer](https://github.com/svgdotjs/svg.js/issues/781) to this after I posted an issue. Here is his response:

> Dont use SVG.Doc directly if you dont know what you are doing:
>
> https://codesandbox.io/s/9ymx30pjxp